# How to use tf-hub models locally

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub, bert-toolkit

I,ve been trying to use a BERT model from tf-hub https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
bert_layer = hub.keras_layer('./bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_2', trainable=True)
```

But problem is that it is downloading data after every run.

So i downloaded the .tar file from tf-hub  https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2

Now i'm trying to use this downloaded tar file(after untar)

I've followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@xianbao.qian/how-to-run-tf-hub-locally-without-internet-connection-4506b850a915

But it didn't work out well and there is no further infromation or script is provided in this blog post

if someone can provide complete script to use the dowloaded model locally(without internet) or can improve the above blog post(Medium).

I've also tried

```
untarredFilePath = './bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_2'
bert_lyr = hub.load(untarredFilePath)
print(bert_lyr)
```

Output

```
<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x7f05c46e6a10>
```

Doesn't seems to work.

or is there any other method to do so..??

Comment: This article helped me in setting it up- https://medium.com/@xianbao.qian/how-to-run-tf-hub-locally-without-internet-connection-4506b850a915  . Hopefully this will help you also

Comment: I've already mentioned about this article in problem. Can you provide further steps or your complete python script so that I can make more sense of it including your folder structure e.g. where is your script and where is untarred model file. Thank You

Comment: I just posted an answer with the script that i was using to cache the models locally. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I cannot reproduce your problem. What worked for me:

`script.sh`

```
# download the model file using the 'wget' program
wget "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2?tf-hub-format=compressed"

# rename the downloaded file name to 'tar_file.tar.gz'
mv 2\?tf-hub-format\=compressed tar_file.tar.gz

# extract tar_file.tar.gz to the local directory 
tar -zxvf tar_file.tar.gz

# turn off internet

# run a test script
python3 test.py

# running the last command prints some tensorflow warnings, and then '<tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x7fd702a7d8d0>'
```

`test.py`

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
print(hub.KerasLayer('.'))
```

Comment: is that a python script or what?

Comment: it's a `bash` script, so you run it using `bash script.sh`

Comment: Can you provide complete script of the above code snippet. Or any script so that i can make sense of it

Comment: This is a complete script, I will add some comments to explain what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this script using this medium article(https://medium.com/@xianbao.qian/how-to-run-tf-hub-locally-without-internet-connection-4506b850a915) as reference. I am creating a cache directory within my project and the tensorflow model is cached locally in this cached directory and I am able to load the model locally. Hope this helps you.

```
import os
os.environ["TFHUB_CACHE_DIR"] = r'C:\Users\USERX\PycharmProjects\PROJECTX\tf_hub'

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import hashlib

handle = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
hashlib.sha1(handle.encode("utf8")).hexdigest()


embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
def get_sentence_embeddings(paragraph_array):
    embeddings=embed(paragraph_array)
    return embeddings
```

Comment: Your answer did help me to make sense of that article and model almost did load. while loading i got this error :  ```Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for C:\Users\devendra\PycharmProjects\NeuralMachineTranslation\tf_hub/276b9d19b6b0a264a5526d08219dfe30923ac454/variables/variables
  [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at /globalEnvironment/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py:102) ]]
  [[save/RestoreV2/_398]]

```

Comment: I've tried with other models also but i got the same error seems this, it is missing any variable file in variable folder or anything else. Have you any idea how to cope with it?

Comment: It seems like a common problem when loading and restoring model check points in tensorflow. I tried searching a workaround for this problem maybe this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6082#issuecomment-289650535 will help you.

Answer (score 1):

After getting information from tf-hub team they provide this solution.
Let's say you have downloaded the .tar.gz file from official tf-hub model page from download button.
You have extracted it. You got a folder which contain assets, variable and model.
You put it in your working directory.

In script just add path to that folder:

```
import tensroflow-hub as hub

model_path ='./bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_2' # in my case
# one thing the path you have to provide is for folder which contain assets, variable and model
# not of the model.pb itself

lyr = hub.KerasLayer(model_path, trainable=True)
```

Hope it should work for you as well. Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

The tensorflow_hub library caches downloaded and uncompressed models on disk to avoid repeated uploads. The documentation at [tensorflow.org/hub/caching](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching) has been expanded to discuss this and other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found the modules downloaded to: **/tmp/tfhub_modules**